# rails: variable showing as method undefined, but object is created successfully

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, object-relationships

I generated the app using scaffolds as such:.

```
    rails generate scaffold server hostname:string
    rails generate scaffold template remote_template_id:integer remote_template_name:string server:belongs_to
```

In my rails controller, for the show method, I want to show all templates owned by the server.

When I run the show action I get the following error:

```
undefined method `remote_template_id' for #<Array:0x007f6b44dc3370>

Extracted source (around line #5):

2: 
3: <p>
4:   <b>Remote template:</b>
5:   <%= @template.remote_template_id %>
6: </p>
7:
```

Here is the code in my template controller:

```
  def show

    server=Server.find(params[:server_id])
    @template=server.templates.all


    logger.info "TEMPLATE OBJECT: " + @template.inspect


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @template }
    end
  end
```

As you can see above, I have some debugging output using the logger, and in the rails server console, the object does get correctly displayed. The object contains the correct data that I am trying to pass into the view.

```
  Server Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "servers".* FROM "servers" WHERE "servers"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
  Template Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "templates".* FROM "templates" WHERE "templates"."server_id" = 1
TEMPLATE OBJECT: [#<Template id: 1, remote_template_id: 12, remote_template_name: "another_debian_derivative", server_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]
  Rendered templates/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms



    ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `remote_template_id' for #<Array:0x007f6b44dc3370>):
        2: 
        3: <p>
        4:   <b>Remote template:</b>
        5:   <%= @template.remote_template_id %>
        6: </p>
        7: 
        8: <p>
      app/views/templates/show.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_templates_show_html_erb___2503859911707707300_70049345896300'
      app/controllers/templates_controller.rb:24:in `show'
```

The database is kosher, relationships are visible; I see server_id is populated into template table.

```
sqlite> .tables
schema_migrations  servers            templates        
sqlite> 
sqlite> .schema servers
CREATE TABLE "servers" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "hostname" varchar(255), "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL);
sqlite> select * from servers;
1|opennebula1|2014-01-28 11:03:02.393136|2014-01-28 11:03:02.393136
sqlite> 
sqlite> 
sqlite> 
sqlite> .schema templates
CREATE TABLE "templates" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "remote_template_id" integer, "remote_template_name" varchar(255), "server_id" integer, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL);
CREATE INDEX "index_templates_on_server_id" ON "templates" ("server_id");
sqlite> select * from templates;
1|12|another_debian_derivative|1||
sqlite>
```

and finally, here is the view code that is erroring, I didnt change or add anything in it, it was generated by scaffold:

```
/app/views/templates$ cat show.html.erb 
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>Remote template:</b>
  <%= @template.remote_template_id %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Remote template name:</b>
  <%= @template.remote_template_name %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Server:</b>
  <%= @template.server %>
</p>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_template_path(@template) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', templates_path %>
```

Help in this matter would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `@template=server.templates.all` will return an array of the template objects. While in the `show.html.erb` you are trying to call `remote_template_id` on this array instead of `template object`.

Comment: Thanks Manoj Monga, that is correct. I assumed wrong in thinking that rails would have this automated.

Comment: Did it work for you then?

Comment: Yes Manoj, that was indeed the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@template=server.templates.all will return an array of the template objects. While in the show.html.erb you are trying to call remote_template_id on this array instead of template object